# Remove null from vector

Tags: kdb

I would like to remove nulls from a vector

```
      a:(2013.05.20 2013.05.21 2013.05.22 0N 0N 2013.05.23)
```

I can see how this can be done by creating a table using

```
      temp:([] a);
      result:exec a from temp where not null a;
```

but I am curious if there is a quicker way that doesn't involve creating a table.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returns the non-null elements

```
result:a where not null a
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the non-null elements using `except` :

```
q)a:(2013.05.20 2013.05.21 2013.05.22 0N 0N 2013.05.23)
q)a except 0N
2013.05.20 2013.05.21 2013.05.22 2013.05.23
```